# Got some unwanted whitespace in css grid layout

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

Playing around with `display: grid` and got some unwanted space. Am I missing some specs in my css?

What I'm after is vertically align the 5 links at the bottom of the purple'ish plane.

[image: screenshot]

Following are the codes I used:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.-twoColumns {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
}

.-grid-gap {
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid -twoColumns -grid-gap">
  <div class="column">
    column
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    column
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which whitespacs ? can you show the code? and what you want ?

Comment: It seems I cannot embed images yet, so SO changed the screenshot to a link. If you view this link, you will see that underneath the 5 links there is another space.

What I'm after is not having that space all together.

Comment: you have to show your code otherwise no one can help you

Comment: I've added the code used... Hope this helps.